# Sublime text 3 increase tab height

Tags: sublimetext3

[image]

Does anyone know how to increase the tab height on sublime text 3? Im using the dark soda theme. Was able to do this on sublime text 2 in one of the themes files but can't seem to work it out on 3. Any ideas?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the `Default.sublime-theme` file do a search for height. You will find a field that displays `"tab_height": 35,` and change that value to your desired tab height.

In Sublime Text 3, the easiest way to find the file is use Package Control and install the `Package​Resource​Viewer` plugin to search for the `Default.sublime-theme` file.

Actual format to be used:

```
[
    {
        // Tabs
        "class": "tabset_control",
        "tab_height": 35,
    },
]
```

Answer (score 5):

Adding more details here:

You can add this to your `Default.sublime-theme` or `{customtheme}.sublime-theme` file

```
[
    {
        // Tabs
        "class": "tabset_control",
        "tab_height": 80,
    },
]
```

Comment: This helped. The above answer should be updated with this solution.