# Sublime Text cutting text in half

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext4

I opened Sublime Text 3 recently on my computer that runs Arch Linux and the text on the tabs and bottom bar looks like they've been cut in half horizontally.

[image]

I tried uninstalling the `sublime-text` and reinstalling it. Same result. I also tried removing the package and installing the `sublime-text-4` package. Same thing.

Comment: Is it only with the sublime-text package that you are facing this issue?

Comment: @EbenezerNikabou Whether it's `sublime-text` or `sublime-text-4`, the result is the same.

Comment: This is apparently a well-known issue. https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/increaseing-font-size-of-file-tabs-cuts-off-the-font/7009

Comment: Doing some hacks like changing the font family and font size may resolve your issue.

Comment: @EbenezerNikabou How do I do that?

Comment: I'm not sure about how to do it since I don't use sublime-text but you can try following this Stackoverflow link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25645565/changing-font-size-of-tabs-strip-in-sublime-text-3.

Comment: Also, this might not be what you want but you can also use vscode and sublime-text theme and keybinds instead. But as I said you might not be willing to change your current editor just for that issue.

Comment: Uninstalling and reinstalling does nothing because your user config remains behind. This issue is indicative of a font issue with the font the theme is using. So as a first step, make sure you're using ST4 and not ST3, and run it via `subl --safe-mode` to see if the problem persists.

Comment: @OdatNurd The problem persists when I run `subl --safe-mode`

Comment: To add some clarity to the answer below, if this is caused by fonts it's caused by the theme font, which isn't in your normal preferences. The road forward here would be to examine the theme that you're using to see what font it's using, and then use your distributions font tool to see what font is mapping to it.

Comment: What build number of Sublime are you running?

Comment: @OdatNurd 4152 from 2023-08-02

Answer (score 0):

Playing with your font settings in your preferences should fix the issue.
[Edit Sublime font preferences](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/font.html)

- You can also [increase the height/ padding of your tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22725938/sublime-text-3-increase-tab-height).

I would also check through your installed linter(s) and see if they may be causing the issue.

Lastly check your computer's display settings and make sure your scaling is at 100% (probably not the issue at hand but worth a check).

Comment: Changing font settings did not work for me. How do I check installed linters? I do not know what those are.

Comment: Linting is the process of flagging suspicious constructs and likely to be bugs in any programming language. Linters do that flagging for you. If you have any installed plugins say like anaconda for python, they may come with a built in linter to pick up common mistakes, sometime these linters override default settings. Go to Sublime Text > Preferences > Package Settings and browse what you may have installed.

Comment: I have Package Control, PrettyJSON and EasyClangComplete in Package Settings.

Comment: Check their settings in their json or text files and see if they are forcing any font updates.

Comment: Nope, nothing like that in there. I also removed all post-installation packages. The text problem still persists.

Comment: @Generic_User_ID I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13781833/sublime-text-2-how-to-change-the-font-size-of-the-file-sidebar/13782271#13782271) check that you edit the correct class for the font family. Also I found you can [increase the height of the tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22725938/sublime-text-3-increase-tab-height).

Answer (score 0):

I re-edited the answer because I verified that this actually has a build problem. The version you are using was fixed in sublime build 3143. Remove this and the settings files and do a fresh reinstall of version 3143 or [higher](https://www.sublimetext.com/3).
https://www.sublimetext.com/blog/articles/sublime-text-3-point-0

[image]

On windows when uninstalling sublime it keeps the settings saved in the json file in the sublime folder in Program Files. You can remove it after you've uninstalled sublime so that when you install it again, you'll get the original settings.

In Linux it is in the user folder, usually hidden in the .config folder

On macOS it is usually in the folder ~/Library/Application Support/

Note: Sometimes outdated or incompatible graphics card drivers can lead to rendering issues in applications. You can try disabling hardware acceleration in Sublime Text by adding the following line to the user settings located in the "Preferences.sublime-settings" file at Preferences > Settings. Disable it with this parameter:

```
"hardware_acceleration": false
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps on how to disable word wrap in Sublime Text on Arch Linux:

1. Open Sublime Text.
2. Press Ctrl+K and Ctrl+S to open the preferences window.
3. Go to the "View" section.
4. Under "Word Wrap", uncheck the "Enable" checkbox.
5. Click "OK" to save the changes.

Once you have disabled word wrap, the text on the tabs and bottom bar should no longer be cut in half horizontally.